# Sample space of Von Neumann's Biased Coin Algorithm

Tags: probability

Edit2: I am trying to find the sample space of Von Neumann's biased coin algorithm
So we flip a coin twice at each time and we return 0 if the result is HT, return 1 if TH, or do it again until we get either HT or TH.

To start off the sample space would be S = {HH, HT, TT, TH, TT TH, TT HT, HH TH, HHHT, HHHH, TTTT, HHTT, TT HH, HH TT HH TH, and so on... }
I figured the sample space will be an infinite series. So I came up with...

Edit: I've come up with something better. S = {$HH^nTT^mHT, n\leq 0, m \leq 0$}

n and m have to be even because we are flipping in sequences of 2
But this only takes care of the case HH TT HT, not if there is something like HH TT HH TH. Where there are more pairs of heads/tails before reaching HT/TH.

Should I introduce more variables or?...

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want here? A detailed description of the sequences? Or just the probabilities for 0 and 1?

Comment: A correct sample space, i feel like mine is incomplete

Comment: What about describing the sample space as a regular expression? Its (HH|TT)*(HT|TH). That's at least neat and short. :-)